# Docker can't start MariaDB/MySQL during Docker build

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, dockerfile

My current `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV INITRD No
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

# Maria DB Versions
ENV MARIADB_MAJOR 5.5
ENV MARIADB_VERSION 5.5.55+maria-1~trusty

# Create mysql user and group
RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql

# Install needed dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add the MariaDB PGP key to verify their Debian packages.
RUN apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db

# Add MariaDB's repository. We use the Ubuntu 14.04 version as there ain't no MariaDB 5.5 for Ubuntu 16.04.
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu trusty main'

# Install Maria DB and open the access for outside of the container
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends mariadb-server=$MARIADB_VERSION \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && sed -i 's/^\(bind-address\s.*\)/# \1/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf \
    && update-rc.d -f mysql disable

# Run as user mysql
USER mysql

# Start the MariaDB to add a user and create the DB
RUN mysqld

RUN echo "@TODO: Create DB, User and grant access"

# Expose Port
EXPOSE 3306
```

When building the container using `docker build -t testmariadb .` I get the following output:

```
    Step 13/17 : RUN mysqld
---> Running in 5aeb49c81f5e
170428 20:00:25 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.55-MariaDB-1~trusty) starting as process 7 ...
170428 20:00:25 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170428 20:00:25 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170428 20:00:25 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170428 20:00:25 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170428 20:00:25 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
170428 20:00:25 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
170428 20:00:25  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
170428 20:00:25  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
170428 20:00:25  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
170428 20:00:25  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170428 20:00:26 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.52-MariaDB-38.3 started; log sequence number 0
170428 20:00:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
170428 20:00:26 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
170428 20:00:26 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
170428 20:00:26 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.55-MariaDB-1~trusty'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

As far as I can tell, it starts the MariaDB, but then is stuck there and doesn't execute a next command. Is there another way to start MariaDB in docker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)It is not stuck. The MariaDB start running. But you need to use CMD command and not RUN command to achieve your purpose.

**The command CMD, similarly to RUN, can be used for executing a specific command. However, unlike RUN it is not executed during build, but when a container is instantiated using the image being built.**

2) The last part of your dockerfile should look like this

```
#Run as user mysql
USER mysql

RUN echo "@TODO: Create DB, User and grant access"

#Expose Port
EXPOSE 3306

#Right way to run mysqld
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

For building your image

```
docker build -t testmariadb .
```

For running the built image

```
docker run testmariadb
```

OR ( for detached mode )

```
docker run -d testmariadb
```

3) Please ask your self why are you using ubuntu base image (FROM ubuntu:14.04). According to me you should use https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/ if you just want to run mariaDb in the container.

Answer (score 0):

For running container what docker command you are using?

Please follow official Docker file for MariaDB.
[Docker MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/)

Here is latest DockerFile [MariaDB](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/21eed39fdd34c84ecd83cc077ad3253cfa875c5c/10.1/Dockerfile)

Comment: Since it hangs, while building, it never get's to running. I'd use `docker run -p 3306:3306 testmariadb`. In our usecase we can't just use the default MariaDB Dockerfile.

Comment: I guess you are trying to use MariaDB on Ubuntu base image. If yes then please check this link  (https://github.com/dockerfile/mariadb)

Comment: Among other things, yes.

Answer (score -2):

this is wrong

`# Start the MariaDB to add a user and create the DB
RUN mysqld`

I guess you wanted

`CMD mysqld`

or such

see from

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/7a850980c4b0d5fb5553986d280ebfb43230a6bb/8.0/Dockerfile

the end is

`EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]`

RUN, WORKDIR, ADD, COPY, ENV (and some others) helps you for configuring your docker image, ENTRYPOINT and CMD for starting your software (nginx for a nginx image, Wordpress...)

The doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/